# Galaxy S5 (Cyanogenmod 13) Bootloop on Decryption

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, samsung-galaxy-s-5

My Samsung Galaxy S5 has Cyanogenmod 13 installed on it; one of the recent nightlies, March 14th 2016 I think. I attempted to encrypt the device. It took a few minutes before rebooting. Now my phone asks me my password and, upon entering it, loads the Cyanogenmod pulsing face logo, where it stays. It has been half an hour so far. Is there anything I can do besides a factory reset in TWRP?

Comment: Yes, please switch to a stable version and report bugs to current developers of that ROM for your device.

Comment: Bit difficult for me to post a screenshot of Settings > About when the device won't boot. You'll note in OP I also state that I think the build is the March 14th nightly.

Comment: Can you please switch to a stable one and then try? We've [a policy](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/recommendation-for-questions-pertaining-to-a-problem-specific-to-a-nightly-build) which would make us close your question because your question is about issues with nightly build of a software. Consider visually confirming us that your device suffers with the same issue even on a stable build and all would be fine with us. By the way, which particular S5 model is it? Its codename?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that policy, my bad. It's a KLTE, SM-G900F.